# ADLS v2 concurrent append

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

Azure Datalake Storage v2 API [path update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update) operation mentions:

> Concurrent writes to the same file using multiple clients are not supported.

Below though the `position` parameter is described as follows:

> This parameter allows the caller to upload data in parallel and control the order in which it is appended to the file.

Does this mean that append works in parallel, but only using single client - like starting with 0-length file and using 10 threads to upload 100 bytes each into positions 0, 100, 200, ..., so that ranges don't overlap? Is there any example of implementing this? Or is this all just inconsistency in the docs?

Comment: I think by concurrent writes it means by different applications at the same time. I have noted problems for example when different spark jobs are writing into same adls folders at the same time. The position parameter helps in this conflict, acting as a traffic controller. When data is uploaded, it gets into a queue to be appended. As the doc says "Uploaded data is not immediately flushed, or written, to the file." suggesting the queuing mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just try it out by myself.

```bash
TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type data-lake -o json | jq -r '.accessToken')
ADLS_FILE='https://xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/adls/foo.txt'
POSITION=0

# Create an empty file in my container "adls"
curl -X PUT "$ADLS_FILE?resource=file" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Length: 0"

# Loop on files (I created a few dummy files 100MB each to merge them)
for f in dummy1 dummy2 dummy3; do
  # Get file length
  LEN=$(stat --printf="%s" "$f")

  # Upload file at given position - in background
  curl -X PATCH "$ADLS_FILE?action=append&position=$POSITION" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    -H "Content-Length: $LEN" \
    --data-binary @"$f" &

  # Calculate current position
  POSITION=$(( $POSITION + $LEN ))
done

# Wait for all uploads to complete
wait

# Flush - commit all what was written so far
curl -X PATCH "$ADLS_FILE?action=flush&position=$POSITION" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Length: 0"
```

Above code works fine and uploads can be done in parallel, in any order, as long as the chunks are nonoverlapping and there are no "holes". Therefore - yes, concurrent writes are supported.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.